# How to create wall posts to app's fanpage from the facebook app?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Every Facebook app can have its own fanpage, so I have a question:
how can I make the app to post to its own fanpage wall? Is there any special authorization or something? Examples (especially in python (facepy anyone?)) would be super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It turned out that every facebook fan page has its own oauth_token, in order to obtain it, you need to authorize fan page admin in your app at first and then, you can get page oauth_token via https://graph.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE_ID_HERE?fields=access_token get request.

Having this access_token you can post to the fan page from your app. That simple!

Here at Facebook docs you can find additional info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/